# Use the same SQS queue for many SaaS software instance with data isolation (multi-tenant)

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs, multi-tenant

I need to use the same queue to many customers to avoid create a new SQS queue to each.
How can I make data isolation in this scenarios?

The queues will be used to integrate an e-commerce with one desktop software (ERP). Each e-commerce have one ERP.

I have to send to the ERP all new orders and customers, the ERP sands to the e-commerce all products, prices update and another situations.

We want to resolve this using queues an I think kafka is so much to this scenario.

Comment: How are these queues being used? If they are used by your own back-end, then why do you require data isolation? If they are being directly consumed by your users, then why do you wan to "avoid create a new SQS queue to each"?

Comment: I update the question with more information, I think its more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible to selectively retrieve messages from an Amazon SQS queue. If you have a central piece of code that reads from the queue and processes the information **across all ERP instances**, then a single queue is fine. However, if you need the code to operate separately for each ERP instance, then you should use separate queues.